# Дорожки для настройки эквалайзера

Tags: android, аудио

Пишем музыкальный плеер под андроид. Возникла задача сделать нормальный эквалайзер. В общем, есть пара вопросов.

Во-первых, если не использовать `ndk`, то стандартный класс `Equalizer` (SDK) предоставляет 5 дорожек (частот), а во многих плеерах под андроид этих дорожек побольше будет.

Во-вторых, надо реализовать громкость, бас и treble. Громкость получилось сделать:

```
float percent=jogView.angle_/(270+0.f);
  int volume = Math.round(maxVolume*percent);
  audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);
```

Ещё в стандартном Эквалайзере есть пресетсы, но их мало:

- Classical,
- Dance,
- Jazz,
- Pop,
- Rock

Вот, если нужно, код дорожек эквалайзера:

```
private void setupEqualizerFxAndUI() {
    // Create the Equalizer object (an AudioEffect subclass) and attach it to our media player,
    // with a default priority (0).
    Equalizer.Settings eqSettings=mEqualizer.getProperties();

    Log.v("Settings",eqSettings.toString());
    TextView eqTextView = new TextView(this.c);
    eqTextView.setText("Equalizer:");
    mLinearLayout.addView(eqTextView);

    short bands = mEqualizer.getNumberOfBands();
    final short minEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
    final short maxEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];

for (short i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
        final short band = i;

        TextView freqTextView = new TextView(this.c);
        freqTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        freqTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        freqTextView.setText((mEqualizer.getCenterFreq(band) / 1000) + " Hz");
        mLinearLayout.addView(freqTextView);

        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this.c);
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView minDbTextView = new TextView(this.c);
        minDbTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        minDbTextView.setText((minEQLevel / 100) + " dB");

        TextView maxDbTextView = new TextView(this.c);
        maxDbTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        maxDbTextView.setText((maxEQLevel / 100) + " dB");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.weight = 1;
        SeekBar bar = new SeekBar(this.c);
        bar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        bar.setMax(maxEQLevel - minEQLevel);
        bar.setProgress(mEqualizer.getBandLevel(band));
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                mEqualizer.setBandLevel(band, (short) (progress + minEQLevel));
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        });

        row.addView(minDbTextView);
        row.addView(bar);
        row.addView(maxDbTextView);

        mLinearLayout.addView(row);
    }
}
```

Как сделать treble, bass? И как сделать больше дорожек для настройки эквалайзера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рамках Java, я полагаю, никак. Достаточно посмотреть исходники класса [Equalizer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.java), чтобы понять, что там захардкодено 5 полос эквалайзера.

Идите в сторону NDK - [например сюда](https://code.google.com/p/sasken-player/).

P.S. Не *дорожки **Е**квалайзера*, а *полосы **Э**квалайзера*

Comment: Я читал документацию эквалайзера, и там мало настроек. Спасибо за пример. А можно ли подключить кусок из ndk безболезненно в джава проект?